# Kerberos with HTTP Resource Server Login

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, single-sign-on

I am having an http (IIS) resource server which uses Kerberos 5 for authentication. Every time I reach the page I need to key in my username and password but if I have done kinit in my machine (Windows 10) and have configured my browser (Firefox) for negotiation based authentication I am in need to type the password only once when I do kinit. Is there any possibility to get this done by just giving the password in the browser only once?